# I am currently trying to write a program that will extract the most occurring ip address from a txt file and display that ip and number of occurrences

Tags: python, dictionary, split, count, strip

example of information in file: 172.16.121.170 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:32] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437

the file contains a list of information as shown in example. I have to read the file into python and extract the ip and display the most occurring one and how many times it occurs.

```
from statistics import mode

def getinput():
    
    d = {}
    file = open("sample1.txt")
    for x in file:
        f = x.split(" ")
        d.update({f[0].strip(): f[0].strip()})

    return d

def counter(d):
    count = mode(d)
    occurences = 0

    for i  in d:
        if i == mode:
            occurences = occurences + 1


    return count,occurences


def display(count,occurences):
    print(count)
    print(occurences)

    
d=getinput()
count,occurences=counter(d)
display(count,occurences)
```

this is what I have done so far, however using mode it only displays the first IP in the list and the occurrences doesn't seem to count as it is only displaying "0".

Comment: It would be useful to see at least the first few lines of the text file to get an idea of other information that may exist within.

Comment: Keys are unique within a dictionary.  `d.update({f[0].strip(): f[0].strip()})` will just overwrite the key if it was already in the dict; it does not add another occurrence.

Comment: And if you want the most occurring ip address, why are you using `mode()` at all?

Comment: the one line example I posted is what is in the text file all the way down the main thing that changes are the IP addresses which is my focus. I can post more of them if that is more helpful ?

Comment: regards to the Key, thank you for informing me, I'm quite new to python and still learning as I'm sure you can tell. I recently learned about mode and thought it could be used for this as its purpose is to display the most occurring I believe.

Comment: As part of the requirements I have to use the .strip and .split as well as keep it as a function. if possible would someone be able to show me how to do it using a loop with a counter.

Comment: 172.16.121.170 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:32] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.17.54 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:34] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.17.108 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:34] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.17.41 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:41] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437

Comment: these are more examples from the text document if those help anyone

Comment: thank you everyone for the help and the input. I'm quite new to python and require to complete this task so any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Python offers a counter already [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

You could try to use an iterator, to avoid having to create an intermediate datastructure, this helps specially if there are many repeated values.

```
import re
from collections import Counter
def get_ips(fname):
    // a pattern to match IPv4
    ip_re = re.compile('^\s*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)')
    with open(fname) as file
      for x in file:
        # extract the IP from the line
        # ignore if it does not have an IP
        ip_match = ip_re.search()
        if ip_match is not None
          # group(1) is the pattern in parethesis, the ip.
          yield ip_match.group(1)

ips = Counter(get_ips("sample1.txt"))
ips.most_frequent(10) # gets the 10 more frequent IPs
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

- Use regex to search for `IP addresses` in text file and append to `ip_list`
- Identify the unique `IP addresses`
- Calculate the number of times each `IP address` is found
- Display the results

#### Code:

```py
import re

ip_list = []
with open('sample1.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        ip_list.append(re.search(r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', line).group())

# Get unique items in the ip_list
unique_ip_list = set(ip_list)

ip_counts = {}
# Find out the the counts for each IP address:
for ip in unique_ip_list:
    ip_counts[ip] = ip_list.count(ip)
    
print(ip_counts)
print()
print(f"Most common IP address: {max(ip_counts, key=ip_counts.get)} with {max(ip_counts.values())} times")
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
{'172.16.121.170': 2, '172.16.121.172': 3, '172.16.121.171': 1}

Most common IP address: 172.16.121.172 with 3 times
```

Tested with the following file:

##### Sample1.txt

```
172.16.121.170 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:32] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.121.170 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:32] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.121.172 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:32] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.121.172 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:32] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.121.172 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:32] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.121.171 - - [03/Sep/2018:09:35:32] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test input file just listing the IP addresses.  You will need to strip lines of logs or whatever to get a listing of just the IP addresses.

text.txt:

```
    192.168.0.34
    192.168.0.13
    192.168.0.45
    192.168.0.34
    192.168.0.62
    192.168.0.34
    192.168.0.13
    192.168.0.13
    192.168.0.62
    192.168.0.13
    192.168.0.45
    192.168.0.62
    192.168.0.45
    192.168.0.13
    192.168.0.65
    192.168.0.45
    192.168.0.10
    192.168.0.45
    192.168.0.7
    192.168.0.45
    192.168.0.92
    192.168.0.45
    192.168.0.12
    192.168.0.45
    192.168.0.14
    192.168.0.45
    192.168.0.32
```

Here is the Python code with comments:

```
    from collections import OrderedDict
    
    ip_occurrences = OrderedDict()
    # open your file
    with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    
       # read all the IP addresses in to a set
       ip_addresses = f.readlines()
    
       # loop through the set of IP addresses
       for ip in ip_addresses:
    
          # my text file had \n codes that needed to be filtered
          #  we will need to remember this when we reference ip_addresses
          #  for lookups as it is not filtered
          clean_ip = ip.replace('\n', '')
    
          # We check our clean IP address to see if it already exists.  
          # We only want to add new ip addresses
          if clean_ip not in ip_occurrences.keys():
    
             # create a new key with the clean_ip name with the count of 
             # the occurnces (not clean) in ip_addresses
             ip_occurrences[clean_ip] = ip_addresses.count(ip)
    
    # winner winner chicken dinner! this is the IP address that occurred the most
    most_freq_ip = max(ip_occurrences, key=ip_occurrences.get)
    
    # display it however you see fit.  I added ip_occurrences[most_freq_ip] to
    # show what the count is
    print( f'{most_freq_ip} occurred {ip_occurrences[most_freq_ip]} times')
```

Produces this output:

**192.168.0.45 occurred 9 times**